# How can path of excess charge be rectangular if electric field on the surface of a conductor is not normal to the surface?

Tags: electrostatics

I have read that "If electric field were not always perpendicular to the surface, a charge could move around a rectabgular path partially inside and partially outside the surfae......violating conservative nature of electrostatic force."

Can someone clarify how charges can go inside the conductor? If it goes, how it comes out?

Answer (score 0):

Let's get very close to a conductor. So close that its surface looks like a straight vertical line. Now we pick a rectangular path that is "partially inside and partially outside the surface", as in the picture:

[image]

We now want to compute the circuit integral of the field over this path. We know that, since the field is conservative, we'll find $\oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{l} = 0$. Since $\vec{E} = 0$ inside the conductor, the line integral over the part of the path that is inside the conductor is surely 0.

About the outside part, if we are close enough that we can consider the field to be uniform, the only way of getting a null line integral is to have the electric field perpendicular to the surface. Indeed, in this way the integral line over the parallel side is trivially 0 (since $\vec{E}$ and $d\vec{l}$ are perpendicular), whereas the line integrals over the remaining horizontal parts have the same value but opposite sign, since $\vec{E}$ is the same but the two $d\vec{l}$ have opposite signs.